# Ionic 2 -- Applying filters on ion list

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a question about filtering an array or ion-list based on some filters that user can apply. Can you please give me a heads up how to do it and what is the best way to achieve this? I want a similar functionality that Amazon provides. see screenshot below. Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you would want to add a [popover](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/popover/PopoverController/) ( which is just another page in ionic 2). In this page you can create the items that you want to filter by.

The communication between the pages , the page for the items that you want to filter and the popover page of the categories to filter by will be done with ionic 2's `navParams` controller and/or the `onDidDissmis` call in the popover controller

**Items page**

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { NavController, NavParams, PopoverController } from 'ionic-angular';
 import { FilterItemsPage } from '../../config/config.pages';

 @Component({
     selector: 'items-page',
     templateUrl: 'items-page.html'
 })
 export class ItemsPage {

      filteredItems:any;

       constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
           public popoverCtrl:PopoverController) {}

       openPopover(){
           let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(FilterItemsPage);
           popover.onDidDismiss(data => {
               this.filteredItems = data
           });
           popover.present();
       }
}
```

So when you click `openPopover()` it will open your page `FilterItemPage` in a popover which then the user can select an item to filter by. The selected filter item then needs to be passed back to the main items page when clicked, which will be handed in the `onDidDissmiss` for the popover. You can hold those items by passing the items that were selected ( and are now held in `filteredItems` ) to the `popover` page, and collect them in the `navParams` - see below

```
// Passing items that have already been added
let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(FilterItemsPage,this.filteredItems);
```

**Now in the popover page ( FilterItemsPage )**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ItemsPage } from '../../config/config.pages';

@Component({
    selector: 'filter-items-page',
    templateUrl: 'filter-items-page.html'
})
export class FilterItemsPage {

     PassedFilteredItems:any;
     itemsToFilterBy:any;

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, 
         public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
         this.PassedFilteredItems = this.navParams.data;
         console.log('Items Page:', this.PassedFilteredItems);
       }

      openPopover(){
          let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(FilterItemsPage);
          popover.onDidDismiss(data => {
              this.filteredItems = data
          });
          popover.present();
      }

      onSelectFilterOrSaveFilteredCollection(){

          // Get selected items from a form ( of model )
          // See angular reactive forms
          // https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/reactive-forms.html

          // Pass items on dismiss 
          // will be passed into onDidDismiss
          this.viewCtrl.dismiss(itemsToFilterBy);

      }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This actually what I used.